# Hard Lagrange multipliers problem - inequalities on constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am given the following two exercises:

[image]

For the first one (letter **e**), I proceeded as expected: wrote the 5 equations corresponding to the equality of the gradients (3 of those) and the other two constraints. I had to split into two cases: one for $\lambda = 0$ and another for $\lambda \neq 0$

[image]

For the exercise on letter **f** I am not sure what to do now. What should I do with the inequality $2z\leq 2x+y+4$? How should I proceed the exercise?

Comment: You can break it down into two subproblems, one for $2z = 2x+y+4$ and one for $2z<2x+y+4$. Do you know how to solve those?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I can do the first one, which is basically the exercise letter e. Not sure about the inequality though.

Comment: In the first one you've already dealt with one inequality $(z>0)$. What sort of trouble do you have with adding another inequality to the mix?